# In Revelation 20:10 when was the beast & false prophet cast into the lake of fire?

Tags: revelation, eschatology

Revelation 20:10 NASB

> [10]And the devil who deceived them was thrown into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet ***are*** also; and they will be tormented day and night forever and ever. Judgment at the Throne of God

According to the above text it seems like Satan is cast into the lake of fire where the beast & false prophet already are.

Does this imply that the beast & false prophet were already in the lake of fire when Satan was cast in?

Comment: They were thrown in at the end of Revelation 19, the previous chapter.

Comment: @MarkEdward,So the beast & false prophet were cast in first?

Comment: At least within the narrative presented in Revelation 19-20: the beast and false prophet are thrown in the fire, the dragon is imprisoned for a thousand years, then the dragon is released, causes trouble, and is also thrown in the fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it cannot be determined, just from that particular place. The original, from the literal translation of the Majority, Received Text in the EGNT, the Englishman's Greek New Testament, states :

> . . cast into the lake of fire and of brimstone **where the beast and the false prophet** and they shall be tormented . . .

I would say that without a verb in the phrase highlighted, and without more information, it could not be further clarified and it may be that the wording is deliberate for it is something that cannot, as such, be understood in physical terms for Diabolos is a spirit; and the beast and the false prophet are a matter of imagery representing concepts, being not specific persons, although their *characteristics* may be recognised in men.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this imply that the beast & false prophet were already in the
>   lake of fire when Satan was cast in?

Yes. They were cast into the LOF at the battle of Armageddon. Satan was cast into the pit rather than the LOF. After being released Satan would be cast into the LOF where the beast and FP were already since Revelation 19.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does imply that the beast and the false prophet had already died and had already been cast into the lake of fire.  The sequence of events starts with vs. 9:

> "9 and they did go up over the breadth of the land, and did surround the **camp of the saints, and the beloved city**, and there came down fire from God out of the heaven, and devoured them;
>
> 10 and the Devil, who is leading them astray, was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, where [are] the beast and the false prophet, and they shall be tormented day and night -- to the ages of the ages."  (YLT)..

where the camp of the saints is identified .. the beloved city was Jerusalem.  The camp of the saints was Jerusalem.  The fire from heaven was the judgment of God carried out by the Roman army that destroyed Jerusalem in A.D. 70.  The actual flames of the burning of the temple and parts of the city were the result of the fire of God's judgment, but God's fire / anger does not have to be a literal fire when carried out.

So, the city and the temple was destroyed, and after that the "devil" was thrown into the lake of fire.  If we identify Nero as the "beast of the sea", and there is much evidence for this, then he had already died in June A.D. 68, so he was already in the lake of fire.  (See info [here](https://www.preteristarchive.com/nero-the-beast-of-revelation/).)

Just as the beast of the sea (Rev. 13:1-10) was the persecuting power of the Roman empire, and collectively centered in the king /Caesar of that political entity, the beast of the land (Rev. 13:11-14) was the persecuting political power of the Sanhedrin, the chief priests and elders of Judea & Palestine.  The false teachers / prophets of Matt. 24:24 were the false prophet collectively of Rev. 20:10.  There were several of them that plagued and distressed the first century Christians before the destruction of Jerusalem.

These false prophets either died during the Jewish-Roman war of AD 66 - 70, or died during the final destruction of Jerusalem.  The devil - the adversary - the deceiving serpent of old (Gen. c.3) was thrown in after the beast and the false prophet.

The sequence of events is laid out in Matt. 22:1-14 in the parable of the wedding feast.

1. The king (God) sent his messengers to announce the wedding of His Son (Christ, and the gospel call).
2. The people of His land killed the messengers.
3. God sent more messengers / servants and the people again killed His messengers (John the baptizer, the disciples & apostles).
4. God's anger / fire (vs. 7) was kindled and He sent His army to destroy that city (Jerusalem).
5. Immediately after the city was destroyed, the wedding took place (vs. 8)( in the full joining of Christ to His bride, the New Jerusalem and the church - Rev. 21:2)).
6. Other quests were called (the Gentiles) to the wedding feast (vs. 9-10).
7. The king enters the wedding feast and judgment began (vs. 11-13).
8. The ones clothed in the proper wedding garments (the righteousness of Christ) were at rest / reclining  (in the kingdom or in heaven).
9. The one who was not clothed in the proper garments (not clothed with the righteousness of Christ) was bound and cast out into outer darkness.

That was the separation of the sheep and the goats (Matt. 25:32-46).  That was the beginning of the judgment of God (Rev. 20:11-12).  After all were judged out of Hades, then God threw Hades into the lake of fire (Rev. 20:12-15).

Hades does not exist anymore. Ever since that time (AD 70) those in Christ go home to heaven when they die, and those not in Christ face the judgment of God and are cast out (Rev. 14:13).

The implication is that THE DEVIL is already being tormented day and night forever and ever, and has been since AD 70.

We are plagued by many adversaries and wicked people today, but they do not need the devil to make them behave wickedly.  That determination is all their own.  That decision to be selfish, greedy, lying, deceiving children of wrath is their decision, and they don't have to have any one entity of evil to prod them to be children of wrath. There is no one else to blame for their actions but themselves.

See more on the judgment day and the end of Hades at my blog [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org) in "The Signs of Revelation - Part VI: The Judgement Day".

Answer (score 0):

**THE BEAST:**
It is necessary to clarify this question because Revelation 17:9-11 demands that the beast is indeed an actual man, albeit, as we will see, ***a resurrected man***:

> And here is the mind which hath wisdom. The seven heads are seven mountains, on which the woman sitteth. And there are seven kings: five are fallen, and one is, and the other is not yet come; and when he cometh, he must continue a short space. And the beast that was, and is not, even he is the eighth, and is of the seven, and goeth into perdition.

That eighth king corresponds with the eleventh king of that Roman world order empire--the little horn of Daniel 7:8:

> I considered the horns, and, behold, there came up among them another little horn, before whom there were three of the first horns plucked up by the roots: and, behold, in this horn were eyes like the eyes of man, and a mouth speaking great things.

The seven kings here in verse eleven are Julius Caesar ***plus*** the first nine emperors of the world-order Roman Empire ***minus*** those three plucked up rogue civil war emperors, Galba, Otho, and Vitellius.

That little horn is that "prince" who Daniel was told "shall come" and destroy the city. That little prince--not at that time yet an emperor, but rather a highly ranked military officer (a prince) who just happened to be the oldest natural born son of **Vespasian**, the tenth horn of Daniel. Vespasian was the seventh horn here in Revelation by eliminating the three plucked up rogue horns mentioned in Daniel. Vespasian was that noteworthy ***"raiser of taxes"*** that Daniel 11:20 describes as that one who finally--following the fiasco of the three plucked up horns--stands up ***"in the glory of the kingdom"***:

> Then shall stand up in his estate a raiser of taxes *in* the glory of the kingdom: but within few days he shall be destroyed, neither in anger, nor in battle.

In the article entitled, "Vespassian", Jay King wrote about Vespasian's extreme notoriety for raising taxes:

> …. One of his few faults was greed. The treasury was depleted after the period of civil war and Vespasian calculated that 400 million gold aurei were needed to put the government’s finances in order. He increased tribute and inheritance taxes. He charged money for appointments to government office and favorable court judgments. He even collected a tax on the products of public urinals, which was used in the hat maker's trade at the time. When his son Titus complained about this method of raising money, Vespasian handed him a silver denarius. "Does this smell?" he asked. One of the strange things about his personality is that he could be so grasping in his business deals but also very generous to people who were down on their luck.
>   http://jaysromanhistory.com/romeweb/empcont/e059.htm

After Vespasian died and after Titus had destroyed the city, Titus became emperor and then also later died. Daniel chapter eleven does not reveal that anyone actually stands up in Titus' estate. His brother, Domitian, and others, became emperors, however, all that is said concerning Titus is that at "the time appointed"--a future time for Daniel--"he shall return", according to Daniel 11:29-32:

> At **the time appointed** he shall return, and come toward the south; but it shall not be as the former, or as the latter. For the ships of Chittim shall come against him: therefore he shall be grieved, and return, and have indignation against the holy covenant: so shall he do; he shall even return, and have intelligence with them that forsake the holy covenant. And arms shall stand on his part, and they shall pollute the sanctuary of strength, and shall take away the daily sacrifice, and they shall place the abomination that maketh desolate. And such as do wickedly against the covenant shall he corrupt by flatteries: but the people that do know their God shall be strong, and do exploits.

**THE RESURRECTED BEAST VS. THE RESURRECTED JESUS CHRIST:**
Daniel chapter eleven did not mention the fourth, fifth, and sixth emperors of Rome because they lie outside the "times" of the prophecy concerning the people of Israel. Jesus was resurrected in the year, 30 AD, during the reign of only the third emperor, **Tiberius**. That ended the 69th week of Daniel's prophecy. The only thing left to cover in chapter 11 was the destruction of the city which had been rebuilt expressly for Jesus to ride into on the colt of an ass, be crucified and then resurrected. The City of Jerusalem and the sanctuary were still standing. Daniel’s prophecy did not require them to be destroyed during the first 69 weeks, but rather sometime—not even necessarily immediately—following the death of Christ.

That **"time appointed"** has not yet taken place, so The beast--a man now physically dead--will return only after his own resurrection--it is appointed unto man once to die, then after this, the judgment. That little horn has died but not yet received his judgment. Jesus has not yet returned to earth to take His throne to reign and judge as promised. Accordingly, both Christ and the antichrist will be resurrected men during the time of this question.

Christs return will mark the beginning of His battle with the beast--resurrected Christ vs. resurrected eighth king of Revelation. As to that future time, it is written in Daniel 11:35:

> And some of them of understanding shall fall, to try them, and to purge, and to make them white, **even to the time of the end:** **because it is yet for a time appointed**. **(My emphasis)**

Messiah will defeat the beast and his false prophet--also a resurrected man--and cast them alive into the lake of fire, as we see in Revelation 19:20:

> And the beast was taken, and with him the false prophet that wrought miracles before him, with which he deceived them that had received the mark of the beast, and them that worshipped his image. These both were cast alive into a lake of fire burning with brimstone.

Notice above that these two men were cast **alive** into the lake of fire. **No man** could withstand the lake of fire unless he were first resurrected to do so--both by God's law and by reality.

**This will mark the beginning of that thousand year reign of Christ.** This will be the event that fulfills that prophecy in Daniel 2:44:

> And in the days of these kings shall the God of heaven set up a kingdom, which shall never be destroyed: and the kingdom shall not be left to other people, but it shall break in pieces and consume all these kingdoms, and it shall stand for ever.

Christ--the resurrected man--son of man--will destroy the antichrist beast--resurrected man--son of man--in the **battle on earth** before the thousand year reign, **HOWEVER**, It appears that Satan will be destroyed in the battle of spirits--God the Spirit vs. Satan the spirit, according to Revelation 20:9 and 10:

> And they went up on the breadth of the earth, and compassed the camp of the saints about, and the beloved city: and fire came down from God out of heaven, and devoured them. And the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are, and shall be tormented day and night for ever and ever.

The righteousness of God is revealed in these two judgments because God, the Spirit father judges no man because He is not a man, as we see in the judgment-of-man context in John 5:22-27:

> For the Father judgeth no man, but hath committed all judgment unto the Son: .... And hath given him authority to execute judgment also, **because he is the Son of man**. **(My emphasis)**

Whether Christ the Son or the Spirit Father judges Satan is not clear here, both of them are eternal Spirit and capable of carrying out this final judgment of Satan, though it appears that the Spirit-Father handles this one perfectly well. God's righteousness demands that ONE Son of man who has been tempted like we men have been tempted, yet without sin, will judge mankind**. **FURTHERMORE**, Satan did not need to be resurrected to withstand that lake of fire judgment because he is already a spirit who was created as an eternally enduring being--no death involved with him.

**THEREFORE:**, The two resurrected men will have been in the lake of fire for a thousand years before Satan is finally cast in there with them.

Parts of this answer contains quotes from my paper, *"The Days of These Kings"*

> https://circumspectnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/The-Days-of-These-Kings.pdf